# How can I read multiple documents from a YAML file?

Tags: ruby, file-io, yaml

I want to make a YAML file that consists of only hashes. However, I cannot iterate over it. When I try to load the YAML file with:

```
YAML.load_file('yamlFile.yml')
```

it returns only the first hash in the file. Here is an example file I would like to create:

```
---
:reach_hypo: true
:liquid: true
---
:reach_hypo: true
:liquid: false
---
:reach_hypo: true
:liquid: true
```

If I load the above file, I get:

```
{reach_hypo: true, liquid: true}
```

The only workaround I have found is to add all the hashes into an array, then write it to the YAML file. Is there a better way, such as a YAML method, to iterate over the YAML file?

Comment: There are no hashes in a YAML file. YAML files consists of mappings (possible tagged), sequences and scalars. A mapping might of course be mapped to hashes in your ruby program. There seems to be an error in the library though, as the first key in the toplevel mapping in the first document in your file is `:reach_hypo` and not `reach_hypo`, which is a different mapping key altogether.

Answer (score 10):

### Read Multiple YAML Documents From Single File as Streams

You can use [YAML::load_stream](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.3.0/libdoc/psych/rdoc/Psych.html#method-c-load_stream) to read multiple documents from a single file. For example:

```
require 'yaml'

array = []
YAML.load_stream(File.read 'test.yml') { |doc| array << doc }
array

#=> [{:reach_hypo=>true, :liquid=>true}, {:reach_hypo=>true, :liquid=>false}, {:reach_hypo=>true, :liquid=>true}]
```

Comment: Yes! that is a possible solution.

Answer (score 0):

I imagine you know this and just want a different solution, but for the record I believe you have exactly two choices.

1. Make an array of hashes.

```
    - a: b
      c: d
    - e: f
      g: h
```

2. Use a two level hash, i.e, name each second-level hash and iterate over the keys in the top level.

```
    x:
      a: b
      c: d
    y:
      e: f
      g: h
```

Comment: I still get the same problem when I load yaml file it only returns the first array. Maybe I am doing something wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

You can try using Psych. It has been around since 1.9.3 but i didn't notice it until today. uses libyaml for parsing. [ruby-doc](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/psych/rdoc/Psych.html)

I tried the following code and works as expected:

```
require 'psych'

hash_arr = Psych.load_stream(File.read('yamlFile.yml'))
#=> [{:reach_hypo=>true, :liquid=>true}, {:reach_hypo=>true, :liquid=>false}, {:reach_hypo=>true, :liquid=>true}]
```

Comment: Psych is the default YAML parser in Ruby since 1.9.3. When you do `require "yaml"` you get Psych. You don't need to do `require "psych"`.

Comment: then, the solution suggested by @CodeGnome should return an array  without passing that block and appending to the array?, because we both call #load_stream, but i get an array of hashes immediately.

Comment: @Jordan you are right, i tried now yaml, it's the same, no block or pushing each doc to another array needed.